# Black screen on login GUI after changing username

Tags: 20.04, login, users, login-screen

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 in a virtual machine.

I only have one user and after some days of use I decided to change the user name.

I changed the user name successfully, but after logging in with this new user name and closing the session I'm getting a black screen and I'm unable to log in again.

These are the commands that I used to change the username:

```
 # login with root: 
 $ sudo su 
 $ usermod -l newuser -d /home/newuser -m olduser
 # Update the username in the login GUI
 $ sudo usermod -c "MyNew User name" <usermame>
```

The `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files were updated with the new username and also `/home/diruser`

What's happening, what I'm doing wrong? I rebooted the system after the change of the username and tried to log in again and I can't log in - a black screen appears.

[image: underscore at top left of screen (no GUI)]

Any idea how to fix this problem?

thanks.